# Sort rows of dynamic datatable by multiple columns using a IComparer<T> typed class

Tags: c#, sorting, datatable, datarow, icomparer

I have an extension method that am trying to sort the rows of a datatable by multiple columns using a IComparer typed class for at least one of the sortings.

The datatable is created with columns whose name and datatype are only known at runtime.  The sort string ("Title ASC, PostedDate DESC") is also created at runtime.

So say my table has columns: ID , Name , PostedDate , Num1 .  My sorting string was "PostedDate DESC, Name ASC", and during the sorting of string column "Name", I want to use custom class of

```
NaturalSortComparer : IComparer<string>
```

I was trying to use the specified IComparer object in the OrderBy call if the column's dataType equaled the TComparerType, but I guess that "the type arguments cannot be inferred from my usage".

Does anyone have any idea of a way I can pull this off?  Thanks in advance.

```
public static EnumerableRowCollection<DataRow> OrderBy<TComparerType>(
    this EnumerableRowCollection<DataRow> rows, DataTable table, string orderBy, IComparer<TComparerType> comparer)
{
    if (table == null || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(orderBy))
    {
        return rows;
    }

    OrderedEnumerableRowCollection<DataRow> orderedRows = null;
    foreach (string sortString in orderBy.Split(new[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.None))
    {
        var trimmedSortString = sortString.Trim();

        int directionIndex = trimmedSortString.IndexOf(" DESC", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
        bool isDescending = directionIndex != -1;

        string columnName = isDescending ? trimmedSortString.Substring(0, directionIndex) : trimmedSortString;
        Type columnType = table.Columns[columnName].DataType;

        Func<DataRow,dynamic> selectorFunc = (row => RowSelectors[columnType](row, columnName));

        Type comparerTypeParameter = comparer == null ? null : typeof(TComparerType);
        if (orderedRows == null)
        {
            if (columnType == comparerTypeParameter)
            {
                orderedRows = isDescending 
                    ? rows.OrderByDescending(selectorFunc, comparer) 
                    : rows.OrderBy(selectorFunc, comparer);
            }
            else
            {
                orderedRows = isDescending 
                    ? rows.OrderByDescending(selectorFunc) 
                    : rows.OrderBy(selectorFunc);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (columnType == comparerTypeParameter)
            {
                orderedRows = isDescending 
                    ? orderedRows.ThenByDescending(selectorFunc, comparer) 
                    : orderedRows.ThenBy(selectorFunc, comparer);
            }
            else
            {
                orderedRows = isDescending 
                    ? rows.OrderByDescending(selectorFunc) 
                    : rows.OrderBy(selectorFunc);
            }
        }
    }
    return orderedRows ?? rows;
}


private static readonly Dictionary<Type, Func<DataRow, string, dynamic>> RowSelectors =
    new Dictionary<Type, Func<DataRow, string, dynamic>>
{
    {typeof(string),   (row,colName)=>row.Field<string>(colName)},
    {typeof(decimal),  (row,colName)=>row.Field<decimal>(colName)},
    {typeof(int),      (row,colName)=>row.Field<int>(colName)},
    {typeof(short),    (row,colName)=>row.Field<short>(colName)},
    {typeof(float),    (row,colName)=>row.Field<float>(colName)},
    {typeof(double),   (row,colName)=>row.Field<double>(colName)},
    {typeof(bool),     (row,colName)=>row.Field<bool>(colName)},
    {typeof(DateTime), (row,colName)=>row.Field<DateTime>(colName)},
    {typeof(TimeSpan), (row,colName)=>row.Field<TimeSpan>(colName)}
};
```

Comment: There's a lot going on in that code.  Do you think you can make a more simple [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Answer (score 0):

When you change

```
Func<DataRow, dynamic> selectorFunc = (row => RowSelectors[columnType](row, columnName));
```

to

```
Func<DataRow, TComparerType> selectorFunc = (row => RowSelectors[columnType](row, columnName));
```

your code will compile.

Comment: No, that causes "One or more types required to compile a dynamic expression cannot be found. Are you missing a reference?" from the file and "Predefined type 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.Binder' is not defined or imported" from the compiler

Comment: For me, it compiles without problems. But I don't have the rest of your code.